Calculate the standard deviation of a distribution
Let's say, we have tick data like the following
,timestamp,close,security_code,volume,bid_volume,ask_volume
2024-04-02 01:00:00.128123+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:00.128123+00:00,18465.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:00.128123+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:00.128123+00:00,18465.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:03.782064+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:03.782064+00:00,18465.25,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,18465.0,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,18465.0,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,18464.75,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:04.112603+00:00,18464.75,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:05.759876+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:05.759876+00:00,18464.5,NQ,1,0,1
2024-04-02 01:00:06.273686+00:00,2024-04-02 01:00:06.273686+00:00,18464.75,NQ,5,5,0

Then one could calculate the current high, the current low and the most often point (the poc) as follows
import pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv("csv/nq_out_daily.csv")
df.drop('Unnamed: 0', inplace=True, axis=1)

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df["timestamp"] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

summary = {"high": [], "low": [], "poc": []}

dist = defaultdict(float)
current_high = current_low = None
for idx, (timestamp, tick, ask, bid) in enumerate(zip(df.timestamp, df.close, df.ask_volume, df.bid_volume)):

    current_high = tick if (current_high is None or tick > current_high) else current_high
    current_low = tick if (current_low is None or tick < current_low) else current_low
    dist[tick] += 1

    summary["high"].append(current_high)
    summary["low"].append(current_low)
    summary["poc"].append(max(dist, key=dist.get))


# plot the summary
fig = plt.figure()
x = range(len(summary["high"]))

plt.scatter(x, summary["high"], s=1)
plt.scatter(x, summary["low"], s=1)
plt.scatter(x, summary["poc"], s=1)

plt.legend(['high', 'low', 'poc'])
plt.savefig(f"distribution.png")
plt.close(fig)

Which would yield the following figure for today

Now, how can I calculate the first standard deviation up and down from the poc?

You don't need to iterate your dataframe to generate your desired data, you can simply use an expanding rolling window with mode from scipy.stats to find the most common value:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import mode

summary = df['close'].expanding().agg({'high' : 'max', 'low' : 'min', 'poc': lambda s:mode(s)[0]})
summary['std'] = summary['poc'].expanding().std()

Output for your sample data:
      high       low       poc       std
0  18465.5  18465.50  18465.50       NaN
1  18465.5  18465.50  18465.50  0.000000
2  18465.5  18465.25  18465.50  0.000000
3  18465.5  18465.00  18465.50  0.000000
4  18465.5  18465.00  18465.00  0.223607
5  18465.5  18464.75  18465.00  0.258199
6  18465.5  18464.75  18464.75  0.322749
7  18465.5  18464.50  18464.75  0.347183
8  18465.5  18464.50  18464.75  0.356000

To plot:
for col in ['high', 'low', 'poc']:
    plt.scatter(summary.index, summary[col].values, s=1)
plt.legend(['high', 'low', 'poc'])


Brilliant! Way to learn... can you say a few words about the expanding rolling window?

@Jan glad I could help. Note I made an assumption about how you wanted to compute the standard deviation; if you only want the overall value just use summary['poc'].std() which will give you just the last value of 0.356 (since that's the standard deviation over all the poc values).

@Jan there's a lot of more general information here, but basically it's a window which includes every row in the dataframe up to and including the current one.

Might open another question but how could one take into account more than one volume at a given price? E.g. when 10 times the volume would be traded on one price level, this would change the "most often traded price" accordingly. How could I implement this within the expanding(...) functionality?

@Jan I think that's probably worthy of another question - although I think I understand what you're saying (you want a volume-weighted average price) having some concrete numbers to work with would make it easier to be sure we're on the same page.

Thanks. Was not clear about the term volume weighted... - with that, I figured it out (+1 for the most famous answer :-)

@Jan I'm glad I got you pointed in the right direction - and thanks! :)
